# Bada, Static pointer crash

Tags: c++, pointers, static, bada

I've got some problem with static pointers and variables in Bada. First I tried to create singleton class and did something like this:
Header:

```
    static Session *getInstanceOf();
private:
    static Session *instance;
```

Source:

```
Session* Session::getInstanceOf(){
    if (instance==NULL){
        instance=new Session();}
    return instance;
}
```

But application crashed without any error message. Then I tried creating static class field and returning it by:

```
ArrayList* User::GetUniv()
{
    return &Universities;
}
```

But it had the same result. Do you have any idea why is it so? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not enough information. Are you using multiple threads? Also, this code leaks.

Comment: Regarding your singleton solution: Did you initialize your Session pointer to NULL? Also where did it crash? Within the getInstanceOf function, or when you use the returned ptr, etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you initialising `Session::instance` in your implementation file? Like this:

```
Session* Session::instance = NULL;
```

**Edit:** Also consider the [`static` initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14).

Comment: Thanks it helped. Surprisingly in both cases. Cheers.

Comment: Cool. In that case you can pick the post that (in your opinion) answered your problem best and accept it by clicking the tick-mark.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
ArrayList* User::GetUniv()
{
    static Universities;
    return &Universities;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat dangerous:

```
if (instance==NULL){
    instance=new Session();}
```

Because your instance doesn't appear to have been initialized to NULL.  Pointers may have a garbage value when uninitialized.